# I asked Allah to punish me in a way if i ever commit a particular sin again and I did it unfortunately, please help

Tags: fiqh, sin, dua, punishment, tawba

Assalamualaikum, I’m new in this sub and to be honest I’ve been so scared because of this. I don’t know if this is counted as an oath. I said to Allah in my mind that i will never watch pornography, then i asked him to punish me if i ever watched Astaghfirullah, I didn’t know asking this was prohibited. Also while saying that I’m sure I didn’t swear by the name of Allah, and I don’t remember if i said i promise. I wasn’t doing well physically and thought Allah is punishing me for my sins. I was extremely anxious and paranoid when i did this. Unfortunately 6 months later i ended up seeing some inappropriate images, my heart’s been shaken with fear thinking about the punishment i had asked during the time my mind was full of fear. What should I do?? I am extremely scared. please help, wasn’t aware that I shouldn’t make dua against myself.